# how to setup Ogre appwizards for VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ogre

So I am trying to integrate Ogre with Visual Studio 2010 to get Ogre project wizard using this program https://bitbucket.org/jacmoe/ogreappwizards/downloads.
I have properly set OGRE_HOME path to my ogre direcrtory and sample projects works fine.
I have also installed Ogre App Wizard from the website above but id doesn;t work.
What should I do ?

Comment: What do you mean for "It doesn't work"? Compiler, linker or runtime error? Try to post more info about the error.

Comment: In Visual Studio there should appear newOgreProject wizard which is not there.

Comment: It's strange. I've tried and it works properly (under Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate). I can see **OGRE Application** under *Visual C++ Templates*. Have you tryed to unistall and reinstall the tamplate? Are you choosing the right version?